# Javascript filter with multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering, reduce

I am filtering items based off of multiple criteria. in my sample I have three different criteria but the final code will have 5 different criteria. My current code works but it is not efficient and now that I have added a third criteria it is getting blotted. I know there has to be a better more efficient way to write the code.

My three filters are: Search, Year & Weeks.

```
return this.list.filter((item) =>{
    let results
    // if search only 
    if(this.search) {
        results = item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
    } 
    // if a year is selected only 
    if(this.whichYear) {
        results = this.checkForDefaultYear(item).includes(this.whichYear)
    }
    // if num of weeks only
    if(this.numOfWeeks) {
        results = item.units.length === this.numOfWeeks
    }
    // if both search and year 
    if(this.search && this.whichYear) {
        results = this.checkForDefaultYear(item).includes(this.whichYear) && item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
    }
    // if neither search or year 
    if(!this.search && !this.whichYear && !this.numOfWeeks)
        results = item.title
    
    return results
    
})
```

The below above works but now that I have added Weeks I have to do something like

```
if(this.search && this.whichYear && this.numOfWeeks) {}
if(this.search && this.whichYear) {}
if(this.search && this.numOfWeeks) {}
if(this.whichYear && this.numOfWeeks) {}
```

This is going to get out of control once I have all 5 filters. This does not seem like the best way to write this code.

Comment: YOu can just return in the `if` self, so you dont need to `&&`

Comment: @0stone0 can you explain? my goal is to allow the user to chain together the filters

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `filter()` which expects a boolean to be returned from the callback (`true` keep the element in the result, `false` exlcude it). Your fallback is to return `item.title` which, assuming it is a string, will be truthy unless it is empty. It looks like you should write some helper functions for each filter type (`search`, `duration`, `year` etc.) which you can then just call in your filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but from what I understand you want to run a series of checks together, depending on whether a user selected certain options or not.

To do so, you can try with this approach:

```
return this.list.filter((item) =>{
    let results = !!item.title; // default filter
    
    // if previous filters and search 
    if(this.search) {
        results = results && item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
    } 
    // if previous filters and year 
    if(this.whichYear) {
        results = results && this.checkForDefaultYear(item).includes(this.whichYear)
    }
    // if previous filters and weeks
    if(this.numOfWeeks) {
        results = results && item.units.length === this.numOfWeeks
    }
    
    return results;
});
```

Here, it works like this:

1. Apply default filter, in this case, the title must be not empty
2. If a user selected the `search` filter, you apply an additional condition to the previous ones (here only default)
3. If a user selected the `whichYear` filter, you apply an additional condition to the previous ones (here default and search)
4. If a user selected the `numOfWeeks` filter, you apply an additional condition to the previous ones (here default, search, and year)

So you basically extend the conditions chain depending on what your user selects. And this way you can add more filters according to your needs.

You could also do a similar thing using arrays: create a `filters` array and `push()` a filter with every condition and in the end, check if every filter returned `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` callback needs a `true` or `false` value.

So the most common way is to `return false` if a check fails, end return true if it's correct :

```
return this.list.filter((item) =>{
    
    if (condition1) {
        return false;   // Invalid
    } 

    if (condition2) {
        return false;   // Invalid
    }

    // Valid
    return true;    
})
```

---

So in your case, you can do somthing like:

```
return this.list.filter((item) =>{

    // if search only
    if (item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) {
        return false
    } 

    // if a year is selected only 
    if (this.checkForDefaultYear(item).includes(this.whichYear)) {
        return false
    }

    // if num of weeks only
    if (item.units.length === this.numOfWeeks) {
        return false
    }
    
    // ...and the rest...

    // Valid
    return true;    
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately when i tried this solution it did not solve my issue.